# cpp: delete folder open by others

Tags: c++, windows

If I really want to delete an (empty) folder, even if someone else has it opened, how can this be done with C++?
With a little help from DOS one could :

1. run `NET FILES` in a DOS box to determine all open files,
2. filter out the ids of the folder in question,
3. run `NET FILES id /CLOSE` in a DOS box with each id
4. Finally, call `RemoveDirectory()`.

How to achieve the same purely in C++?  (And I do not want to delay until reboot)

Comment: Can you show what code you have some far, and what kind of problems you have with it ?

Comment: Erm, after creating a minimal code example and playing with it, it seems that a simple `RemoveDirectory()`is sufficient - it nonchalantly closes even handles of  other sessions on the directory. Then the bug I observe I my code must be something else - I may be back soon with a better question, this one's nonsense ...

Answer (score 1):

This might have worked in DOS but in a modern OS this can not be done.

On Windows you can use [MoveFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240) with the `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT` flag if the folder is in use.

```
MoveFileEx(folderName, NULL, MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT);
```

Comment: I specifically said I did not want ot delay until reboot.